# Check/uncheck input checkboxes in Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-isotope

I have a simple Isotope grid with checkbox inputs to sort the items in a grid. This works OK. The problem is the interaction between the "Show All" checkbox and the different category checkboxes.

When "Show All" is checked, I have to manually uncheck it to be able to check any category checkboxes. And when I uncheck all the categories, I'd like to have "Show all" check itself to indicate that all category items are being shown.

https://codepen.io/bluedogranch/pen/MWvdyNm

[image: isotope grid layout]

1. How can I have "Show All" uncheck itself when any one or all of the categories are checked?
2. How can I have "Show All" check itself when all of the categories are unchecked?

and

3. How can I have "Show all" be checked on page load?

**jQuery**

```
var $container = $('#container').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.product',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    transitionDuration: '0.2s'
  });
  
  var $checkboxes = $('#filters input');
  $checkboxes.change(function(){
    var filters = [];
    // get checked checkboxes values
    $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(){
      filters.push( this.value );
    });
    filters = filters.join(', ');
    $container.isotope({ filter: filters });
  });
```

**CSS**

```
.product  {
float: left;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border: 1px solid #000;
padding:10px;
text-align:center;
margin: 5px;
}

#container {
width:400px;
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="filters">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="*"  id="all">Show all</a></li>
<label><input type="checkbox" value=".category1" id="category1">Category 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value=".category2" id="category2">Category 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value=".category3" id="category3">Category 3</label>
</div>

<div id="container">

<div class="product category1">1</div>

<div class="product category1 category2 ">1,2</div>

<div class="product category1 category3">1,3</div>

<div class="product category2">2</div>

<div class="product category2 category3">2,3</div>

<div class="product category3">3</div>

<div class="product category3 category2">3,2</div>

<div class="product category1">1</div>

<div class="product category2">2</div>

<div class="product category3">3</div>

<div class="product category2">2</div>

<div class="product category1">1</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About #1 and #2, just check during the event which target was changed. You can do this by accessing `event.currentTarget`.

```js
  $checkboxes.change(function(event) {
```

After this, just add the logic:

```js
    let currentTarget = event.currentTarget;
    // if all is selected, deselect others
    if (currentTarget.id == "all")
      $("#filters input:not(#all)").prop("checked", false);
    else // remove the checked prop from all
      $("#all").prop("checked",false);
    // if none is checked anymore, check all
    if (!$checkboxes.filter(":checked").length)
      $("#all").prop("checked", true)
    // your code
    var filters ...
```

And about the 3rd one, just add the `checked` property to the input field.

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" value="*" checked id="all">Show all</label>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I ended up using `$('#all').prop('checked', true); $("#filters input:not(#all)").prop("checked", false);` with on document ready instead of `checked` in the html input in order to force "Show all" and uncheck others on page load. Codepen updated.